# How to Model PowerBI Data to show the exact Date

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have a PowerBI report that contains bar graphs that date and other information and a Bing Map that is linked with the bar graph. Now the bing map contains latitude and longitude and some other information like date, and it has the same date column that is used inside the bar graphs. Now I am using a drill through feature here which drill through the map when I select a bar graph and use any of the data visuals inside the map to drill through, now when I drill through this other page contains different information of the bar graph like date and other things.

The problem is when I use drill through on a certain visual inside a map I dont get the exact date that is shown inside the tool tip of the map and the bargraph, thats why because I have the same longitude and latitude that contains different dates and the drill through feature is just showing me the latest date of that longitude and latitude, how can I make this useful so that I get the exact date which I can see earlier on the tooltip of the map and the bar graph any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a sample of your dataset to better understand your problem. The flow you have mentioned is not clear.

Are you drilling from bar graph to Bing map which is on another page?

Comment: nah I have 2 visuals bar graph and the bing map, I have applied drill through on map both the bing map and bar graph contains a date value, and the page on which I am drilling through also contains a date value which shows the exact date of the bar graph which I select (Suppose I select a bar graph that contains date as 22nd november then the drill through page should show me the date value as 22nd november), Problem is there are same long,latit on differnet date, and the drill through page does not able to understand which date I want it gives me 2 options earlies and latest date.

Comment: I cant provide you the data set, but try to think it as I have 3 columns longitude latitude and Date, and there are various same values in the case of long,latit that have different dates on these, How can I show exact date when I drill through another page? thats the only concern here!